# Spring boot: Using Async method as sync method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, scheduler, spring-async

I have some scenario

1. scheduler(call repeatedly) should call  for a async function say fun().
2. Controller should call same function fun() and return result based on successful completion(By checking exception)

Please provide me some skeleton with appropriate notations.

Comment: Provide some sample code to illustrate your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have your method as sync, but if you want to call your async methd, inside of your async method you should call your sync method.

```
public void mySyncMethod(){
   //whatever you want. 
}
```

Async method

```
@Async
public void myAsyncMethod(){
   mySyncMethod();
}
```

I supposed you are using spring boot